When foreground service is running app won't start
When I start my foreground service and close the app it keeps running, but when I try to open the app again it won't open.
Smallest repro sample is
    package pro.themed.manager.utils

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import pro.themed.manager.R

class MyForegroundService : Service() {


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startForegroundService()
    }

    private fun startForegroundService() {
        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java) as NotificationManager

        val notificationChannelId = "ForegroundServiceChannel"
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.palette_48px).setContentTitle("AutoRefreshRate")
            .setContentText("Service is running...")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
            notificationChannelId, notificationChannelId, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        )

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

        startForeground(1001, notificationBuilder.build())
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val actualIntent = intent ?: Intent() // Use an empty intent if it's null
        return super.onStartCommand(actualIntent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        stopSelf()
        stopService(Intent(this, MyForegroundService::class.java))
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}

and maybe this crashlog is related tho I'm not sure
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
RisingOS Version: '3.2'
Build fingerprint: 'google/rising_arm64_bgN/arm64_bgN:14/AP1A.240505.005/eng.nobody.20240602.131323:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2024-06-27 13:28:49.046541942+0300
Process uptime: 1s
Cmdline: pro.themed.manager
pid: 9621, tid: 9630, name: ADB-JDWP Connec  >>> pro.themed.manager <<<
uid: 10569
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x000000000000000d
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  00000071999f49b0  x1  000000000000000b  x2  000000744977bda0  x3  000000744977be20
    x4  0000000000001070  x5  0000000000000000  x6  00000071845fde28  x7  000000000000406e
    x8  49f8b631b95192d9  x9  49f8b631b95192d9  x10 00000071845ffc40  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 0000007199147440  x13 00000071845fdf40  x14 0000000000000000  x15 00000071845fe350
    x16 0000007440867338  x17 000000744ed30b94  x18 00000071203d0000  x19 000000744977be20
    x20 000000744977bda0  x21 000000000000000b  x22 00000071999f49b0  x23 0000007440878000
    x24 00000071845fda80  x25 00000071845ffc00  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000007440878ab8
    x28 0000007440877828  x29 000000744977bc90
    lr  000000744085a010  sp  000000744977bb50  pc  00000071991ed300  pst 0000000060001000
44 total frames
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000425300  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::FaultManager::HandleSigsegvFault(int, siginfo*, void*)+68) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #01 pc 000000000001300c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libsigchain.so (art::SignalChain::Handler(int, siginfo*, void*)+540) (BuildId: aafbcdcdfebea6543a1b39991214687f)
      #02 pc 00000000000005c0  [vdso] (__kernel_rt_sigreturn+0)
      #03 pc 00000000009c3b00  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #04 pc 00000000004ed458  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+584) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #05 pc 000000000062333c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+13000) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #06 pc 00000000003819d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #07 pc 0000000000155500  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.putChar+0)
      #08 pc 00000000003db648  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.6516773938084655443)+64) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #09 pc 00000000003db3bc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.6516773938084655443)+416) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #10 pc 00000000004ee06c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+3676) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #11 pc 000000000062333c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+13000) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #12 pc 00000000003819d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #13 pc 00000000003cd440  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.ddm.DdmHandle.putString+0)
      #14 pc 00000000003db648  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.6516773938084655443)+64) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #15 pc 00000000003db3bc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.6516773938084655443)+416) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #16 pc 00000000004ee06c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+3676) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #17 pc 000000000062333c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+13000) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #18 pc 00000000003819d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #19 pc 00000000003cb9cc  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT+0)
      #20 pc 00000000003db648  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.6516773938084655443)+64) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #21 pc 00000000003db3bc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.6516773938084655443)+416) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #22 pc 00000000004ee06c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+3676) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #23 pc 000000000062333c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+13000) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #24 pc 00000000003819d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #25 pc 00000000003cb958  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk+0)
      #26 pc 00000000003db648  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.6516773938084655443)+64) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #27 pc 00000000003db3bc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.6516773938084655443)+416) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #28 pc 00000000004ee06c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+3676) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #29 pc 000000000062333c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+13000) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #30 pc 00000000003819d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #31 pc 000000000003efd4  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar (org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch+0)
      #32 pc 00000000003db648  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.6516773938084655443)+64) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #33 pc 000000000030d430  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+2100) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #34 pc 000000000037f498  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #35 pc 0000000000368e40  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+640) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #36 pc 000000000030dea8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+220) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #37 pc 00000000007ce38c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::detail::ShortyTraits<(char)76>::Type art::ArtMethod::InvokeStatic<(char)76, (char)73, (char)76, (char)73, (char)73>(art::Thread*, art::detail::ShortyTraits<(char)73>::Type, art::detail::ShortyTraits<(char)76>::Type, art::detail::ShortyTraits<(char)73>::Type, art::detail::ShortyTraits<(char)73>::Type)+84) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #38 pc 00000000007cdb04  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Dbg::DdmHandleChunk(_JNIEnv*, unsigned int, art::ArrayRef<signed char const> const&, unsigned int*, std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> >*)+276) (BuildId: 3a0499bbf274a88a639802f270ec45c5)
      #39 pc 0000000000015a70  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libadbconnection.so (adbconnection::AdbConnectionState::HandleDataWithoutAgent(art::Thread*)+932) (BuildId: 2e746ca4bb90e0964d82e45deb9ddd87)
      #40 pc 0000000000014cc8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libadbconnection.so (adbconnection::AdbConnectionState::RunPollLoop(art::Thread*)+1808) (BuildId: 2e746ca4bb90e0964d82e45deb9ddd87)
      #41 pc 0000000000013184  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libadbconnection.so (adbconnection::CallbackFunction(void*)+1344) (BuildId: 2e746ca4bb90e0964d82e45deb9ddd87)
      #42 pc 00000000000cdf58  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208) (BuildId: 8a199c85eb786c47b29919b38cf88684)
      #43 pc 0000000000069b30  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 8a199c85eb786c47b29919b38cf88684)

I've tried putting it into coroutines or thread but it doesn't seem to do anything. LogCat doesn't contain anything useful.
